# Find the generating function, $f(x)$ of the squence $a_n =\binom{-3}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, generating-functions

As you can expect, $f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-3}{n} x^n = (1+x)^{-3}$ by the "generalized binomial theorem". But I tryied to find $f(x)$ without using that formula, Binomial thm. I took $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n = \frac{1}{x+1}$. Since $a_n = (-1)^n(n+1)(n+2)$, I have to do only finding $f(x) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^2g(x))$. The reason why claim like is $ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^2g(x)) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(n+1)(n+2)x^n$. Therefore the answer is $f(x) = \frac{2}{(1+x)^3}$

When I used the formula $f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-3}{n} x^n = (1+x)^{-3}$ But without using the theorem, $f(x) = \frac{2}{(1+x)^3} (\neq (1+x)^{-3})$. What the point did I missed? I can't find my errors in my solution.

Regards.

Comment: $\binom{-3}{n}=(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\neq (-1)^n (n+1)(n+2)$

Comment: @Gary Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.